# How to set domain for a local html file?

Tags: html, dns, local, hosts

I have a local html file. I can open it with a browser at file:///a.html

I want to see it at http://example.com/a.html.

I am not going to run a server.

I tried to edit the hosts file, add a line:

file:///  example.com

it dosn't work.
how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the "http" protocol any other way. Without a web-server of some sort, your only option is to use the file protocol.

With regard to the hosts file, it is used to define mappings from IP addresses to a host name. As such, trying to define a URL will not work.